# Rename the app in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have almost finished my iPhone app, but want to rename it as I don't like the name I chose in the beginning. Is this easy to do, and if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what rename does, but there are a possible 5 names to deal with.  There's the name of your .xcodeproj file directory, the name of your target within that project, the Product Name under Packaging in the Build Settings, and the Bundle Display name in the Info.plist, and the name you provide for the app in iTunes Connect.  None of these 5 names needs to be the same, and you can name them all slightly differently.  In fact this is common.

For instance, you might want the Bundle Display Name to be short so that it will fit under the icon, and it can have spaces in it.  The Product Name can be much longer and more descriptive, but can't have spaces.  You iTunes Connect name might be longer still, with spaces, and you may have change the spelling, etc. slightly if your preferred spelling is already taken, etc.

Comment: There's also the suffix of the appID, which can be yet another unique identifier name.  That's 6.  The Xcode template names your app delegate.  That's 7.  Any more I missed??

Answer (score 2):

Go to target-> yourApplicationName(double click/get Info)->Build->ProductNAme

Set your new name for that application there

hAPPY cODING...

Comment: Not Changing.
Is there any thing to chage more

Comment: Please select all configuration while setting it.. if you have selected active setting then it will not reflect if you change the running sdk version. So Select `all Configuration`. It worked for me iand i have tested it also. Else wise do the same in the topmost folder in the tree in xcode project. `DONT FORGET ALL CONFIGURATION`

Comment: Extending on this for later versions of XCode (4.6.2) target->AppName->BUILD SETTINGS->list titled Packaging->Product Name

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of xcode.

Project > rename.

Choose new name.

[image]

Comment: There is no Such option(rename)

Comment: Did you look at the 3rd item under the Project menu.  What does it say for you?

Comment: @lavanya: there should be. Are you using an old version of Xcode (**Xcode > About Xcode**) by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently and tried Project -> Rename, as well as Target -> application name -> Build -> ProductName

Then, I remembered the .plist file.  If you double click the .plist file in your app's resources folder, you'll see "Bundle Name".  Changing this did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
Change your bundle display name in info.plist file
```